# The c++ function returns an object defined inside the function, whether it is a transfer or a copy

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> foo()
{
//do something
...

//define my vector
vector<int> result;

//do something
...

return result;
}

vector<int> v = foo();
```

I have no idea what happens when tha above function returns. Does it recopy the vector defined in the function once and then destructure it, or does it assign its address directly to v? My understanding is that both approaches are the correct semantics, but clearly there is a performance gap, especially if the vector is particularly large.

Would like to get more detailed information about this issue to help me understand why c++ would choose one of both methods to implement this functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: Lookup Return Value Optimization

Comment: It will be moved or maybe compiler uses copy elision.

Comment: Define your own class with the proper diagnostic messages and see what happens. You can also do it online with compiler explorer.

Comment: Could you return by reference?

Comment: @John it's not possible to return a reference/address to an automatic storage variable

Comment: @Mehran `static` it..

Comment: @John It's not possible or efficient sometimes.

Comment: @Mehran _"It's not possible"_ Whoever told you that?

Comment: @Mehran https://rextester.com/VOELP37333

Comment: @John the programer may not want to share an static variable multiple times, so it's not good always.